# SO needs an automatic delay regarding up votes, down votes, and close votes

Tags: discussion, voting

imho, there are members of SO who so quickly up vote/down vote and close vote that it is highly unlikely that they have read a given post thoughtfully.

The solution would be to add an appropriate time lag to prevent this from happening.

My only guess for the prevalence of such careless behaviour is that there are members that are treating SO as if it were a first person shooter video game in which they are trying to score reputation points rather than be thoughtful and helpful.

BTW, do members get points for up/down votes cast and for close votes cast? if they do, that would be like putting traffic police on a quota system to issue a minimum number of parking tickets.

Comment: _"BTW, do members get points for up/down votes cast and for close votes cast?"_ No, they don't. In contrary they'll loose rep when downvoting answers.

Comment: There are much more questions that can be spotted as being invalid within a second, than the other ones that need to be read through. Anyway there's also a form of **TL;DR;** questions that could be spotted as invalid within the same time.

Comment: The voter gains nothing at all for themselves in Up- Down- or Close- voting,  IMHO, more Voting needs to be *encouraged* (up and down) not thwarted.

Comment: here's where i'm coming from:  more than once i've asked a question and seen responses that to me clearly indicate that thoughtfulness was missing from the answer.  When persons down vote and fail to give a reason, then it is natural to wonder whether it is nothing more than a hit and run.  Whereas down voting may make sense regarding the answers, i'm not so sure that it is a good idea for the questions.

Comment: OK, while I spend my time reading thoroughly all the questions that I already know suck badly from the title, when do I answer the good questions?

Comment: @MartinJames -- from your comment, it appears that you are claiming to have the *skill* to evaluate a question simply from its title.  Thus, it follows that *for you* a terrible title could never mask an excellent question.  Further, speculating that likely the majority of community members have some language other than English as their mother tongue, many of their titles may not meet your particular standard and thus will likely not even be read by you, let alone answered by you.  Rather than cherry picking titles, i suggest you read their text and answer the ones for which you are capable.

Comment: @gerryLowry - I do have thast skill,  It's not 100% accurate, so I so waste time checking how really, really bad they are.  If it's a false negative, I don't DCV.  ' terrible title could never mask an excellent question' - no, your interprtation of a 'terrible title ' seems to be different to mine - I don't particularly care about spelling, punctuation errors or cultural differences, just bad questions, and I've got quite good at spotting them early.

Answer (score 30):

I actually find it both a little offensive and amusing that you could allege that some of us don't actually read or understand a question before we down vote it, and that you conflate quickness of action with careless behavior. Further, you've failed to provide any examples to back up your opinion, and you seem to have not done any research first to find how many times similar solutions have been proposed already. If you have solid examples of questions that don't deserve down votes then you should present them.

You've been around Stack Overflow for some time, and you've also been a programmer for a long time. You of all people should value high quality questions and answers. As an old timer you might be used to dealing with specifications written on a Post-It note, but would you ever answer a customer query given little more detail than *"my code doesn't work"*? You wouldn't and shouldn't - you would demand far more detail. This site unapologetically requires the same, and the voting mechanism is one way of representing this.

Comment: This, so much. There are (were) plenty of low quality answers and questions out there that required a mere second or two to see they're worth a downvote / closevote. Heck, I've closed questions as dupes within 30 seconds of them being posted. Fast actions aren't necessarily uninformed actions. Adding any kind of delay would only serve to discourage experienced users from maintaining the site's content.

Comment: slugster, you yourself marked a question of mine as a duplicate that is obviously not a duplicate.  FWIW

Comment: slugster, yes, i do value high quality questions and answers; for example, see [*Clarity is important, both in question and in answer.
*](http://weblogs.asp.net/gerrylowry/clarity-is-important-both-in-question-and-in-answer)  BTW, Post-It notes did not exist when i first dealt with specifications.

Comment: Hiya @gerryLowry, based on your updated info in your closed question I have cast a reopen vote. Note that when posting the onus is on you to say why your question is not a duplicate. You've done that now, so it's up to the community to reopen it. Also note that the original close vote was not because we didn't read it, it's because initially it seemed similar enough to an existing question (even though worded differently) to close as a dupe - IOW closing that question was not an example of the behavior you mention in your question here.

Comment: @gerryLowry But having said that sometimes mistakes will happen - but the community at large can also reverse those mistakes.

Comment: slugster ... thank you.  much appreciated.  yes, i too make mistakes.  i also appreciate the efforts of our peers to make SO and other forums work for the greater good of all.  This old timer remembers when vendors had their own paid technical support staff. `B-)`